# MySQL Rejecting Elixir 1.9 Connections

Tags: mysql, docker-compose, elixir

I've updated from Elixir 1.8.2 -> 1.9.0. MySQL now rejects the connection with the error: `Aborted connection 7 to db: 'some-api' user: 'some_user' host: '172.28.0.5' (Got an error reading communication packets)`

This application is running within a `docker-compose` and works fine on Elixir 1.8.2.

When starting the database with `docker-compose`, then running the Elixir app with `MYSQL_HOST=localhost iex -S mix phx.server`, the application works fine, which leads me to believe this issue is more related to Docker than it is Elixir

I've tried upping the MySQL `max_packet_allowed` variable in `[mysql], [client], [mysqld]` sections of the configuration to no avail.

`docker-compose.json`:

```
{
  "version": "3",
  "services": {
    "some-api": {
      "build": {
        "args": [
          "MYSQL_HOST=some_mysql"
        ],
        "context": "./../some-api"
      },
      "container_name": "some-api",
      "depends_on": [
        "some_mysql",
      ],
      "networks": [
        "somenetwork"
      ],
      "ports": [
        "4000:4000"
      ],
      "volumes": [
        "./../some-api:/code/some-api",
        "/code/some-api/deps"
      ]
    },
    "some_mysql": {
      "container_name": "some_mysql",
      "environment": {
        "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD": "password"
      },
      "image": "mysql:5.7",
      "networks": [
        "somenetwork"
      ],
      "ports": [
        "3306:3306"
      ],
      "volumes": [
        "./services/mysql/db:/var/lib/mysql",
        "./services/mysql/config:/etc/mysql/conf.d"
      ]
    },
  }
}
```

Elixir config:

```
config :some_repo, SomeRepo.Repo,
  database: "some-api",
  username: "some_user",
  password: "some_pass",
  hostname: "some_mysql",
  port: 3306
```

Comment: Update: we're using `myxql` as a dependency and according to https://travis-ci.org/elixir-ecto/myxql there is not yet a build for Elixir 1.9

Answer (score 0):

`iex` ended up being the problem.  When we switched the command to `elixir` (keeping everything else the same), it worked.

Still unsure of the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove `_build` and recompile. Then it worked.